# What is the range of hue values in `Color.init(hue:saturation:brightness:opacity:)`?

Tags: swiftui, undocumented-behavior

[The `Color` initializer `init(hue:saturation:brightness:opacity:)` is undocumented](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color/init(hue:saturation:brightness:opacity:)).

I think I can safely assume that `saturation`, `brightness`, and `opacity` normalize to the range of `0...1`, where values outside that range are valid only for wide-gamut displays.

But I can't make this guess for `hue`. Is is `0...1`, `0...τ`, or `0...360`?

Answer (score 2):

Happily, it's easy to test this quickly.

I tossed this code into a new SwiftUI app and just looked at the preview to see the results. Turns out, **it's `0...1`!**

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Color(hue: 0/6, saturation: 1, brightness: 1)
            Color(hue: 1/6, saturation: 1, brightness: 1)
            Color(hue: 2/6, saturation: 1, brightness: 1)
            Color(hue: 3/6, saturation: 1, brightness: 1)
            Color(hue: 4/6, saturation: 1, brightness: 1)
            Color(hue: 5/6, saturation: 1, brightness: 1)
            Color(hue: 6/6, saturation: 1, brightness: 1)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image: A screenshot proving that the range is 0...1 by showing colors with hues 0/6 through 6/6 in a VStack]